# How to speed up the calculation of cross entropy loss in tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to make a multi-label classification model (each example has multiple labels and the number of labels for each example are not fixed). For instance, example1 may have class labels "X", "Y", while example2 have class labels "X", "Y", and "Z". My goal is calculate the cross entropy loss for this multi-label classification model.

My first solution is to manually create the dense one-hot representation of target class and calculate the loss. However, this solution is slow when my vocabulary is of size O(10K). I wonder whether there is a more efficient way to do this?

[Update to provide the relevant code]

```
## During the data input phrase
def input_fn():
    ... 
    ## target_ids is a sparseTensor
    target_ids = lookup_table.lookup(target_label_strings)

    ## change the dense_shape 
    st2 = tf.SparseTensor(indices=target_ids.indices,
                          values=target_ids.values,
                          dense_shape=[batch_size,vocab_size])

    ## Convert to dense Tensor
    st2_ordered = tf.sparse_reorder(st2)
    dt = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(st2_ordered)

    ## Row normalization
    dt_float = tf.cast(dt, tf.float32)
    dt_float = tf.add(dt_float, tf.constant(1e-10))

    dt_row_norm = tf.reduce_sum(dt_float, axis=1)
    target["target_ids"] = dt_float / tf.reshape(dt_row_norm, (-1,1))

    return feature_map, target

## Model training
def get_loss_fn(self, target, weights, mode):
    ...
    ## the self.final_logit is the final output layer
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
      labels=target["target_ids"], logits=self.final_logit))
    ...
```

Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post your own implementation of the function.

Comment: Add the pesudocode in the original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to deal with large vocabularies when doing softmax cross entropy in TensorFlow is to use [tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sampled_softmax_loss)

Comment: I see. Thank your for answering.